# add two laser for navigation

Tags: navigation, move-base, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all
i want to use two laser scan device for navigation is it possible?

when i add two laser source in costmap_common_params.yaml only one of sources work!

how i must add my second laser device?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34095/add-two-laser-for-navigation/) by [farshid616](https://answers.ros.org/users/1501/farshid616/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2012-05-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Below is the configuration that I used to successfully launch two observation sources in my costmaps. I'd guess you may have forgotten to add the second source to the list of sources in the `observation_sources` parameter.

```
observation_sources: sick_lms_1 sick_lms_2

sick_lms_1: {sensor_frame: sick_1,
        data_type: LaserScan,
        topic: /scan_1,
        expected_update_rate: 0.4,
        observation_persistence: 0.0,
        marking: true,
        clearing: true,
        min_obstacle_height: 0.0,
        max_obstacle_height: 2.0,
        obstacle_range: 9.0,
        raytrace_range: 10.0}

sick_lms_2: {sensor_frame: sick_2,
        data_type: LaserScan,
        topic: /scan_2,
        expected_update_rate: 0.4,
        observation_persistence: 0.0,
        marking: true,
        clearing: true,
        min_obstacle_height: 0.0,
        max_obstacle_height: 2.0,
        obstacle_range: 9.0,
        raytrace_range: 10.0}
```

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3